# How do i create a delivery date range in Js

Tags: javascript, date, range

Currently I have this code that allows me to change the special christmas delivery date. This year we are offering 3 delivery dates - 21, 22 and 23. How do I manipulate this code to allow a range such as this?

Current code :

```
setValidDaysForNationwideDelivery: function(date) {
    if ((date.getMonth() == 11) && (date.getDate() == 21)) {
        return [true, ""];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a range:

```
setValidDaysForNationwideDelivery: function(date) {
if (date.getMonth() == 11 && date.getDate() >= 21 && date.getDate() <= 23) {
return [true, ""]; }
```

---

Side note: The extra `()` around each comparison (`date.getMonth() == 11`) have absolutely no effect, I've removed them above.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
setValidDaysForNationwideDelivery: function(date) {
  date = date.getMonth() + '-' + date.getDate();
  var range = ['11-21', '11-22', '11-23'];
  if (range.indexOf(date) !== -1) {
    return [true, ""];
  }
}
```

The advantage of this method: next year you will only have to remplace the dates in range variable and you can put anything you want.